# Is there any way to edit HTML pages from browser/editor without seeing source code

Tags: html, frontend

I know that using browser developer tool we can edit HTML page. But is there any way to edit it without going into source code. For example if I want to bold some text then I just need to select that text and enter Ctrl+B.

Answer (score 0):

Without opening the devtools: unless the webpage specially supports it, no.

But if you're willing to run a tiny bit of JavaScript, the answer is yes!

```
document.querySelector('body').contentEditable = true
```

Just run that code in the devtools console, then try selecting some text on the page and using `ctrl + b`

This works because of [Content Editable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content). Of course, the changes are temporary and the page returns to normal when you refresh it.